# solution of 1st order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of PDE, $$u_xu_y = u$$ with the initial condition $u(x,0) = 0$ in the domain $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.

I have try the method of characteristic, but it seems like not working for me. 
Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: This probably isn't too helpful, but just from observation, $u=xy$ is a solution

Comment: how can you have that observe ? can you please show me how

Comment: $u=0$ is also a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=v^2$ ,

Then $u_x=2vv_x$

$u_y=2vv_y$

$\therefore2vv_x2vv_y=v^2$ with $v(x,0)=0$

$4v^2v_xv_y=v^2$ with $v(x,0)=0$

$v_y=\dfrac{1}{4v_x}$ with $v(x,0)=0$

$v_{xy}=-\dfrac{v_{xx}}{4v_x^2}$ with $v(x,0)=0$

Let $w=v_x$ ,

Then $w_y=-\dfrac{w_x}{4w^2}$ with $w(x,0)=0$

$\dfrac{w_x}{4w^2}+w_y=0$ with $w(x,0)=0$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$ , letting $y(0)=0$ , we have $y=t$

$\dfrac{dw}{dt}=0$ , letting $w(0)=w_0$ , we have $w=w_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{4w^2}=\dfrac{1}{4w_0^2}$ , letting $x(0)=f(w_0)$ , we have $x=\dfrac{t}{4w_0^2}+f(w_0)=\dfrac{y}{4w^2}+f(w)$ , i.e. $w=F\left(x-\dfrac{y}{4w^2}\right)$

$w(x,0)=0$ :

$F(x)=0$

$\therefore w=0$

$v_x=0$

$v(x,y)=g(y)$

$u(x,y)=G(y)$

$u_x(x,y)=0$

$u_y(x,y)=G_y(y)$

$\therefore G(y)=0$

Hence $u(x,y)=0$