# Solve the pde $u_xu_y=u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I want to solve the following pde $$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
u_xu_y=u  \mbox{ on $\Omega:=\{(x,y)|x>0\}$} \\
u(0,y)=y^2 
\end{array}\right.$$
I supposed that $u$ was a polynomial of two variables of degree 2 and I found that $u(x,y)=y^2+\frac{1}{2}xy+\frac{1}{16}x^2$ is a solution of the pde.
I want to know if there is way to solve this pde without guessing what the solution looks like.

I thought of using the characteristic method but I think there's missing a condition on the first partial derivatives of $u$ to use this method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can transform the problem along the lines of what is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413344/solution-of-1st-order-pde) to get a first order PDE solvable via the method of characteristics.